# Twitter Embedded Timeline Disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm embedding a twitter timeline via Jquery so that when a user clicks on a button, it creates the div with the timeline... when he clicks on it again, the timeline disappears.

This works, but when I click on the button again, it doesn't want to load again. So I only get one load per page.

```
$("#TWT").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if(loadHtml == "empty") {
        $( "#authorName" ).load( "test.html" );
        loadHtml = "full";
        } else if(loadHtml == "full") {
            $("#tweetDiv").remove();
            loadHtml = "empty";
            }
    });
```

The test.html contains the embedded content, and loadHtml is set to empty.

My actual implementation was more complex but I've whittled it down to this so I can see what's wrong. The div containing the twitter feed reappears... but the feed does not load again.

Is there an issue with serving the embedded timeline more than once to the page without loading? If I refresh page, again it works... only once.

**PS: Just to clarify - this is not an issue of the div not showing up again. It shows up just fine when I look at the html that's generated. It's just that Twitter does not want to load again.**

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced a similar problem and solved it.
You must have included some javascript like that provided by twitter:

```
        !function(d,s,id){
            var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
            if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                console.log("executed");
                js=d.createElement(s);
                js.id=id;
                js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
            }
        }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

I solved the issue by commenting the if() statement:

```
        !function(d,s,id){
            var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
            //if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                console.log("executed");
                js=d.createElement(s);
                js.id=id;
                js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
            //}
        }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, is #tweetDiv a parent of #authorName? If it's the case, $("#tweetDiv").remove() will cause #authorName to also be removed from the DOM, meaning that your next .load() is targeting no element on the page.

On a side note, if you're going to show/hide stuff, I'd advise using .show() and .hide(), which are less expensive on the browser, as it doesn't alter the DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, #tweetDiv is not the parent of #authorName. I've also tried this by creating a var with all the twitter embed code and then putting it in (without load). So the div still appears properly as I have put text in it (besides the twitter code), it's just that the twitter embed shows only ONCE.